# Cordova SQLite, Push value from server and insert into SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

My hybrid application is pushing data from server to cordova application when user on the application. From my server, I have 2000 data in my JSON. I successfully inserted 2000 data into my SQLite database. However, I realize that the program inserted 2000 same data as the last data in server. The following is my code.

```
      $http.get("http://131.4.44.69/php3/fetchSAPInfo.php?key=" + lastSAPOID).success(function (data){
              alert(lastSAPOID);
              if(data == 1){
                  alert("data is up to date");
              }else{
                  alert("data is updating......");

                  var i;
                  for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                      var SAP_OID =  data[i].SAP_OID;
                      var SAP_Asset = parseInt(data[i].SAP_Asset);
                      var SAP_Description =  data[i].SAP_Description;

                      db.transaction(function(tx) {
                          alert(SAP_Asset);
                          tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SAPInfo VALUES (?,?,?)', [SAP_OID, SAP_Asset , SAP_Description]);

                      }, function(error) {
                          console.log(error);
                      }, function() {
                          alert("insert successfully");
                      })
                }
            }              
    }).then (function (response){
          alert("done and finished");
    });
```

I realize that the code, go to then function first only run db.transaction() function. Therefore the program do not get JSON data accordingly my for loop. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spend whole day to figure it out what is the problem. My for loop must put inside db.transaction() function. This is the problem with asynchronous programming. The following is the answer work for me.

```
      $http.get("http://131.4.44.69/php3/fetchSAPInfo.php?key=" + res).success(function (response){
              if(response == 1){
                  console.log("data is up to date.......");
              }else{
                  console.log("data is updating.........");

                  db.transaction(function(tx) {
                   var i;
                       for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
                            var SAP_OID =  response[i].SAP_OID;
                            var SAP_Asset = parseInt(response[i].SAP_Asset);
                            var SAP_Description =  response[i].SAP_Description;

                            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SAPInfo VALUES (?,?,?)', [SAP_OID, SAP_Asset , SAP_Description]);
                       }
                   }, function(error) {
                          console.log(error);
                   }, function() {
                          console.log("insert successfully");
                   })
            }
    }).then (function (response){
          console.log("done and finished");
    });
```